# Website as portal/gateway for internal websites

Tags: networking, vpn, webserver, website

I have a few web services that are currently publicly open, but I want to change this.

I realize that I could simply set up a VPN into the network to access the services, but this seems like a boring solution.

What I am looking for is a way to have a single public website, that has links to all the internal sites, without having to open any other ports than for the main website. 
Kind of like a "VPN in a website", is this possible?

Comment: Apache Web Server can do this with the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives (both available with `mod_proxy` enabled) which are detailed in this [official Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a very common thing to do, and it's commonly known as a "reverse proxy".

Now that you know the term to search for, you should be able to find lots of tutorials on how to set up various web server software packages to act as reverse proxies for your other local websites. For example, on nginx, look at the "proxy_pass" directive.